# How do I create different number of threads in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, pthread-join

In my program, I want to get number of threads from user. For example, user enters number of threads as 5, i want to create 5 threads. It is only needed in the beginning of the program. I don't need to change number of threads during the program. So, i write the code such as;

```
int numberOfThread;

cout << "Enter number of threads: " ;
cin >> numberOfThread;

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThread; i++)
{
    pthread_t* mythread = new pthread_t;
    pthread_create(&mythread[i],NULL, myThreadFunction, NULL);
}

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThread; i++)
{
    pthread_join(mythread[i], NULL);
}

return 0;
```

but i have an error in this line **pthread_join(mythread[i], NULL);**

error: ‘mythread’ was not declared in this scope.

What is wrong in this code?
and do you have a better idea to create user defined number of thread?

Comment: You have a memory leak when creating threads. I suggest you using `std::thread` instead of `pthread_t` and not using pointers at all.

Comment: Your `mythread`-variable is local to your `for`-loop, it does not exist outside of it.

Comment: You also have undefined behaviour: for any value of `i` > 0 `mythread[i]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have a memory leak when creating threads because you allocate memory but then loose the reference to it.

I suggest you the following: create an `std::vector` of `std::thread`s (so, don't use `pthread_t` at all) and then you can have something like:

```cpp
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numberOfThread; i++) {
    threads.emplace_back(myThreadFunction, 1);
}

for (auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

if your `myThreadFunction` looks like:

```cpp
void myThreadFunction(int n) {
    std::cout << n << std::endl; // output: 1, from several different threads
}
```

Comment: @DikotaLolly please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you